# Different gateway method implementations

Tags: methods

Sometimes I need to use the same use case with different details implementation. It is easy and straightforward for presenters as each use case has its own output port and therefore different implementations.

BUT in the data layer, there are Gateways that have different abstract methods used in different use cases.

The problem is that I need sometimes to use different implementations of a gateway’s method. but I don’t need to override all the gateway’s methods.

Example:

- `GetUserDetails` use case:

  1. When I open the user from the users list, the `getUser()` method will get info from local storage.
  2. When I open the user’s details page from a notification or a deep link, `getUser()` method will fetch info from the web.

So `getUser()` should have different implementations.

What is the proper solution?

Possible solutions:

- To segregate `getUser()` method in a new interface.
- determining the source of data in the use case request model
- creating two different use cases

Comment: All of what you listed are solutions that could make sense in certain contexts. But you could also just derive from the existing implementation and override the single method. Just make sure there's some organization to it, otherwise the number of classes could explode (in that case, the differences in implementation are better handled either via composition (allows you to combine things dynamically), or by decision logic).

Comment: I could have missed something important, but I get the feeling that this's a job for `Strategy Pattern`.

Comment: It sounds like you are using some specific design, framwork, or pattern. But it is not clear to me exactly what you mean with 'use case' and 'gateway' etc. These can mean quite different things depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

If you can identify user information needed, regardless of source, you can use polymorphism to limit what code is aware of the source.

If you can’t you’re stuck writing corner cases. Try to limit this awareness of source.